# AllUsers Activity stops working

Tags: java, android

I created AllUsersActivity where it has to get and show all registered users. But it crashes and returns to MainActivity. Maybe there is an error in this line: `Picasso.get().load(user_image).into(image);`

**Please, write in comments if you need to see more code.**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class AllUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView allUsersList;
    private DatabaseReference allDatabaseUserReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_users);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.all_users_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Users");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        allUsersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_users_list);
        allUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        allUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        allDatabaseUserReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUsersViewHolder>
                (AllUsers.class, R.layout.all_users_display_layout, AllUsersViewHolder.class, allDatabaseUserReference) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(AllUsersViewHolder viewHolder, AllUsers model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setUser_name(model.getUser_name());
                viewHolder.setUser_status(model.getUser_status());
                viewHolder.setUser_image(getApplicationContext(), model.getUser_image());

            }
        };

        allUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    public static class AllUsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public AllUsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setUser_name (String user_name){

            TextView name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_username);
            name.setText(user_name);

        }

        public void setUser_status (String user_status){

            TextView status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
            status.setText(user_status);

        }

        public void setUser_image (Context ctx, String user_image){

            CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);
            Picasso.get().load(user_image).into(image);

        }

    }
}
```

---

**Debugger**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.chatting, PID: 21652
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                      at com.example.chatting.AllUsersActivity$AllUsersViewHolder.setUser_status(AllUsersActivity.java:83)
                      at com.example.chatting.AllUsersActivity$1.populateViewHolder(AllUsersActivity.java:54)
                      at com.example.chatting.AllUsersActivity$1.populateViewHolder(AllUsersActivity.java:48)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:196)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1767)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:356)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

---

**Logcat**

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.airliner.chatting.AllUsersActivity$AllUsersViewHolder.setUser_status(AllUsersActivity.java:83)
        at com.airliner.chatting.AllUsersActivity$1.populateViewHolder(AllUsersActivity.java:54)
        at com.airliner.chatting.AllUsersActivity$1.populateViewHolder(AllUsersActivity.java:48)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:196)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1767)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:356)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

Comment: can you paste the error message for that line?

Comment: Provide a logcat output?

Comment: I added Debugger error.

Comment: I think your 'setUser_status' method is trying to set a TextView with a LinearLayout, make sure you are assigning the correct XML value to the 'status' TextView

Comment: Is `all_users_status` in your xml code a linear layout by any chance?

Comment: yes, all_users_status is in Linear layout.

Comment: Have you find any solution? If not i will send you the corect code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I added by mistake TextView id to LinearLayout.